# using android ListView onItemClick to select specific Item in slide menu

Tags: android, onclick, slide

OK guys, so after 4 hours of struggling i finally decided to ask here my problem. I developed a slide menu with a listView. I got the slide menu all good and i managed to make it doing just one action if one of the Items is clicked. My problem is that i do not know how to manage it further. I am thinking about making a switch case statement but the problem is that i cannot use "position" due to: "position cannot be resolved to a variable"
Here is my list code so far:

```
 public class RandomList extends SherlockListFragment{

String[] list_contents = {
    "Add me on Google+",
    "Linkedin",
    "W&T Top Tips Forum",

};

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final ListView list1;
    list1 = getListView();
    list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>    (getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_contents));  

    list1.setOnItemClickListener(
            new OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

                    Object listItem = list1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    //long index = arg0.getSelectedItemId();

    switch(position){
```

}

```
                    Intent myWebLink = new         Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://plus.google.com/u/0/115467961053443202630/about"));
                        startActivity(myWebLink);

                }   
            }       
    );

}
```

}

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. i edited now and i explained better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variable arg2 in the switch case.This indicates the position of the item which has been clicked.